# Breadth first traversal of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, breadth-first-search

I am making a program that solves a puzzle game, and it finds all the possible moves on a board and puts all the possible resulting boards in an object. Then it finds all the possible moves for the resulting boards, and so on. The object will look something like this:

```
{
  "board": {
      "starts": [[0,0],[0,3]],
      "blocks": [[3,0],[3,3]],
      "ends":   [[2,4]]
  },
  "possibleMoves": [
    {
      "board": {
        "starts": [[0,0],[2,3]],
        "blocks": [[3,0],[3,3]],
        "ends":   [[2,4]]
      },
      "possibleMoves":[
        {
          "board": {},
          "possibleMoves": [{}]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "board": {
        "starts": [[0,3]],
        "blocks": [[3,0],[3,3]],
        "ends":   [[2,4]]
      },
      "possibleMoves":[{}]
    }]
}
```

I can figure out how to add the possible moves from the top-level board, but I cannot figure out how to loop through all the resulting boards in the second level and figure out their possible moves, and then loop through all the third level boards and so on. How can I add the possible moves and traverse the object using a breadth-first search?

Comment: You might want to do a search for "recursion" and "recursive functions" on here and the web in general should be a wealth of info.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Recursion.

```
function traverse(state) {
    handle(state.board);
    if (state.possibleMoves) {
        $.each(state.possibleMoves, function(i, possibleMove) {
             traverse(possibleMove);
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** For a breadth-first search, try something like this. It doesn't use recursion, but instead iterates over a growing queue.

```
function traverse(state) {
    var queue = [],
        next = state;
    while (next) {
        if (next.possibleMoves) {
            $.each(next.possibleMoves, function(i, possibleMove) {
                queue.push(possibleMove);
            });
        }
        next = queue.shift();
    }
}
```

Comment: On second thought, won't this handle the first level and then traverse the first board in the second level, handle it, and traverse the first board in the third level, and so on? I want it to handle the first board, then traverse all of the boards in the second level before it starts handling anything in the third level.

Comment: Right. In that case, you'll need to implement a queue. What I've shown you is a depth-first traversal. You want a breadth-first traversal. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search for a decent algorithm.

Comment: Ok. I guess I wasn't very clear about what I wanted. I revised the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely tested:

```
var oo = {
    board: {
        starts: [[0,0],[0,3]],
        blocks: [[3,0],[3,3]],
        ends:   [[2,4]]
    },
    possibleMoves: [{
        board: {
            starts: [[0,0],[2,3]],
            blocks: [[3,0],[3,3]],
            ends:   [[2,4]]
        },
    }],
};


function traverseObject (o) {
    for (var prop in o) {
        if (typeof o[prop] == "array" || typeof o[prop] == "object") {
            traverseObject(o[prop]);
            console.log(prop);
        } else {
            console.log(prop, "=", o[prop]);
        }
    }
}

traverseObject(oo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a JavaScript description but i would generally do it by keeping a queue of unexplored nodes.

1. Start with only the root node in the queue.
2. Pop an item from the front of the queue
3. Explore it add all of the nodes found during exploration to the back of the queue
4. Check if there are any nodes in the queue if there are go back to step 2
5. Your done

Also there is some pseudopod on the Wikipedia page as well as some more explanations
[HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Also a quick Google search turned up a similar algorithm that could be bent to your purpose
[HERE](http://www.mattsnider.com/javascript/breadth-first-dom-search-algorithm/)