# JavaScript - Graph traversal - Get nodes in order (nearest first) from a starting node

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, traversal, graph-traversal

I have got a graph which looks like this :

```
root : {
    nodeType : "root",
    children: [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
    ]
}
nodes : [
"A": {
    nodeType : "node",
    children: [
    "D",
    "E"
    ]
},
"B": {
    nodeType : "node",
    children: [
    "D",
    "F"
    ]
},
"C": {
    nodeType : "leaf"
},
"D": {
    nodeType : "node",
    children: [
    "G"
    ]
},
"E": {
    nodeType : "leaf"
},
"F": {
    nodeType : "leaf"
},
"G": {
    nodeType : "leaf"
},
]
```

I need to write a javascript function which, given a starting point (for example "B"), would traverse the graph in a closest-to-starting-point-priority way. For example for B, it would get children D, F, then root, then siblings B, C, then granchild G, then childs of B and C and so on.

Even just having the algorithm would be fine

PS: I know that I could use a dijkstra in there but I don't really figure out how

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) implemented for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411270/breadth-first-traversal-of-object). Dijkstra's algorithm would be needed if the edges in your tree had weights associated with them.

Since you do not keep the parent in the node objects, you will need to add a preprocessing step to add a parent field to all nodes. This is needed so that when starting at `B` you know to visit the root. This can be done using a simple traversal.

Breadth-first search keeps the nodes that you need to visit in a queue. New nodes are added to the end of the queue. The algorithm picks new nodes to visit from the front of the queue.

Be careful though, because the queue can grow very large if revisting nodes is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cyon advice about using breadth first algorithm, I came up with this
(based on http://java.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-graph-breadth) :

```
var graph = {
    A : [B, C],
    B : [A, D],
    C : [A, D],
    D : [A, C ,E],
    E : [B, F],
    F : [E]
};

function init (visited, graph) 
{
    for (var key in graph) {
       var vertex = graph[key];
        visited[key] = false;
    }
}

function breadthFirst (graph, start, visited)
{
    // Create an empty queue
    var queue = [];

    // Initially enqueue only the starting vertex
    queue.push(start);

    //Set the starting vertex to visited
    visited[start] = true;

    //Add it to the result
    result.push( start );

    //While there is still remaining vertexes in queue
    while (queue.length > 0) {

       //Remove first vertex from queue and save it in "t"
       var currentVertexID = queue.shift();

       //For each key in graph at "t"
       var currentVertex = graph[currentVertexID];
       for (var key in currentVertex) {

       var target = currentVertex[key];

            //If it has not been visited yet
            if (!visited[target]) {

                //Mark it as visited
                visited[target] = true;

                //Add it to queue
                queue.push(target);

                //Save it in result
                result.push(target);
                //console.log(result);
            }
        }
    }
}

var result = [];
var visited = [];
init(visited, graph);
breadthFirst(graph, 2, visited);    
console.log(result);
```

And because I had a separated root, and only parent to children relations in my graph (because I migrated from a tree), I had to build up a full relation matrix before using breadth first (so that it could look up parents).

I post it because it can be useful for preprocessing in order to use breadth first on a tree

```
generateNodesAdjacencyMatrix : function(){
            var adjacencyMatrix = {};
            function recursiveFindNestedAndSaveLinks(parentKey, childrenKeys){
                //Add the links to parent pointing to his children
                if(!_.isArray(adjacencyMatrix[parentKey])){
                    adjacencyMatrix[parentKey] = [];
                }
                adjacencyMatrix[parentKey] = adjacencyMatrix[parentKey].concat(childrenKeys);

                //For each children
                _.each(childrenKeys, function (childKey){
                    //Add a link to parent
                    if(!_.isArray(adjacencyMatrix[childKey])){
                        adjacencyMatrix[childKey] = [];
                    }
                    adjacencyMatrix[childKey].push(parentKey);

                    //If it has children as well, do recursive on him
                    var child = childs[childKey];
                    if(!_.isUndefined(child) && !_.isUndefined(child.children)){
                        recursiveFindNestedAndSaveLinks(childKey, child.children);
                    }
                }, this);
            }
            recursiveFindNestedAndSaveLinks('root', root.children);
            return adjacencyMatrix;
        },
```