# How can I use breadth first traversal to add attributes to each node

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an incremental id attribute to the following architecture

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "a",
    children: [
      { name: "b", children: [{ name: "e"}] },
      { name: "c", children: [{ name: "f"}] },
      { name: "d", children: [{ name: "g"}] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "a2",
    children: [
      { name: "b2", children: [{ name: "e2"}] },
      { name: "c2", children: [{ name: "f2"}] },
      { name: "d2", children: [{ name: "g2"}] },
    ],
  },
];
```

And hope his final result looks like this, how to use javascript to achieve it

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "a",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      { name: "b", id: 3, children: [{ name: "e", id: 9 }] },
      { name: "c", id: 4, children: [{ name: "f", id: 10 }] },
      { name: "d", id: 5, children: [{ name: "g", id: 11 }] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "a2",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      { name: "b2", id: 6, children: [{ name: "e2", id: 12 }] },
      { name: "c2", id: 7, children: [{ name: "f2", id: 13 }] },
      { name: "d2", id: 8, children: [{ name: "g2", id: 14 }] },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411270/breadth-first-traversal-of-object

Comment: That was a fun problem to solve. What I did was recursive loop over each level pushing the children to an array. After I got them in the 2D array, I looped over that and assigned ids.